# How can I make a cell in tableview that has multiple fields?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make a tableview with different people. You can add a person by clicking the add button. When you click the add button, you fill out the information 'first name','last name',and 'date'. When you click the done button, it goes back to the tableview and the cell shows the persons first name.

I created a new swift file that has a struct:

```
struct person {
   var firstName : String
   var lastName : String
   var date : String
}
```

In the tabledetailviewcontroller.swift (controller where you add a person) I declare IBOutlets for each field and set each value:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dateText: UITextField!

let first:String = ""
let last:String = ""
let date = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "doneSegue" {
        first = firstName.text
        last = lastName.text
        date = dateText.text
    }
}
```

In the tableviewcontroller.swift I have declared an array of people with type 'person':

```
var people = [person]()
```

and a function that returns the number of people in the array.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return people.count
}
```

then I have a function that sets the text value of the cell
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->

```
UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("issueCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

   //cell.textLabel.text = issues.dateTime[indexPath.row] //Fixed this to this =>
   cell.textLabel.text = (issues[indexPath.row]).dateTime

   return cell
}
```

finally I have a done button that appends the new person to the array (this part keeps giving me errors...)

```
@IBAction func done(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
        var addPersonVC = segue.sourceViewController as AddPersonViewController
        let newPerson = person(date: (addPersonVC.date)) //Breaks here for no reason!

        people.append(newPerson)
    }
```

My question is, how can I make each cell store multiple fields (first, last, date), save it in under each person and have the person's name show up in the cell in the tableview? I want to be able to edit a cell and change information about that person.

I am very new to swift :/
I greatly appreciate it!

EDIT: I have fixed a few things, now it breaks at the done function!

Comment: Standard practice is to go to a new view for entering the new record, then return when they're done. You could use a table view for entering the new record's fields, or you could just use text fields.

Comment: I have 2 views: one for the actual table, and the second which comes up when you click add and it has all the text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong or missing some code, you have two errors:

1. your struct is called "person" (small p), but you instantiate the new Person with Person(date: (addPersonVC.date))
2. if the properties of your struct are declared with let, you need to define them in the initialization as they are constants. Otherwise you have to call them var

Comment: Good call! I fixed those, but it still breaks at this line:
 let newPerson = person(date: (addPersonVC.date))

When I debug, the 'date' value of newPerson is some weird value! but the 'addPersonVC.date' shows the correct date. Am I not setting the date value of newPerson the right way? It's supposed to get the date from the addperson view controller and set it to the newPerson date value..

Comment: can you update your code above to see how the function looks now? And check if addPersonVC.date is not nil

Comment: addPersonVC.date = "Nov 18 2014, 3:40 PM" so it's not nil. But when I assign it to newPerson like I mentioned above, it gives me some weird values and then breaks at that line.

Comment: Your struct still expects all values to be initialized because they are not optional. You can change it to `struct person {
 var firstName : String?
 var lastName : String?
 let date : String
 init(date1: String) {
  date = date1
 }
}`